# Cannot set property 'onaddtrack' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, html, events

I'm learning about HTML media. There's an example of detecting track addition:

```js
const mediaElem = document.querySelector("video");
mediaElem.audioTracks.onaddtrack = function(event) {
    audioTrackAdded(event.track);
}
```

My HTML code is the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Multimedia</title>
</head>

<body>

    <video controls loop muted poster="images/poster.png"
        width="400" height="400">
        <source src="videos/rabbit320.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="videos/rabbit320.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <p>
            Your browser doesn't support HTML5 audio. Here is a <a href="audio/viper.mp3">link to the audio</a> instead.
        </p>
    </video>

    <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And the JS code (*script.js*):

```js
var videoElem = document.querySelector('video');
videoElem.audioTracks.onaddtrack = function (event) {
    console.log(event.track);
};
```

In console I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onaddtrack' of undefined at script.js:2

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/audioTracks).

Comment: I'm using Opera which is said to have full support.

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with your code, could you check output in console for this jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/ae3zhmgs/ , it should display `[object AudioTrackList]`

Comment: No :( it goes with `else` branch. Tried on Mozilla v78 too, still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HTMLMediaElement.audioTracks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/audioTracks) property is still behind a flag as described here https://caniuse.com/#feat=audiotracks

The compatibility table on MDN is probably incorrectly showing the feature as supported in Opera.